# Php commands are not outputing result in windows

Tags: php, windows, composer-php, command-line-interface

I have wamp install on my computer and IIS. All the websites are running well but then any command I type using php is not working :

```
php -v 
php composer install
```

I would say it is the path variable (I am on windows) but the path is set correctly and it would generate an error of not finding php command. When I run those command I simply don't get any result.

[image]

What might be the problem, I am still searching but have not found any clue.

```
php -h
```

: return result with all the help information  but `php -a` does nothing too.

After doing some research I found that this problem happens when I activate an extension by remove ; in php.ini whenever I leave php.ini without activating any extension everything works.

Comment: Is the full `php.exe` path in your windows environment variables?

Comment: Yes it is there, otherwise php -h could not even work

Comment: First thing I would do is check the error log (configured in php.ini) maybe there is something wrong with the ini itself.

Comment: I went inside php.ini but could not know where the problem might be and the weird thing is it doing the same for all the version of php I have with my wamp... it was working well but suddenly after me test IIS it stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. To see if the problem was with php.ini, I replaced the content of my `php.ini` with the `php.ini-production` file which made the php function well but almost all the extensions were desactivated.

As I was analysing I noticed wamp had many php extensions activated but in my php.ini residing under C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.5 none of these extensions were activated following the path the file used by wamp I found it was using the `phpForApache.ini` via a link `php.ini` file inside `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.39\bin`

Since the wamp php configuration was working well, I just copied the content of that `phpFOrApache.ini` content in my php.ini after saving ... everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the path contains php, also using the `cd` command, move to the location of the file and run the command you want to execute. If it works, you're sure the problem is the windows path.

Comment: Try to run cmd as an admin first... Sorry I don't really know for Windows...

Comment: Still nothing is coming out.